# How do I append values fo an observed array in RxSwift

Tags: arrays, swift, rx-swift, behaviorsubject

Trying to grasp `RxSwift` and get stuck on a few things.

```
var observedData = BehaviorSubject.from([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    .map({$0*3}).subscribe(onNext: {
        print("HELLO", $0)
    })
```

How do I `append` an extra value to the array, so that the `subscription` is triggered again?

I tried `observedData.onNext` and `observedData.accept` but they don't work.

I also would like to know the difference between

```
var observedData = BehaviorSubject.from([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

and

```
var observedData2 = BehaviorSubject<[Int]>(value: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

I first assumed it was different ways of writing the same thing, but I can't use `.map` on `observedData2`

Comment: maybe you need smth like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832750/observe-array-in-swift-3-using-rxswift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that should work :

```
let subject = BehaviorSubject<[Int]>(value: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
subject.asObservable().map({$0.map({$0*3})}).subscribe(onNext: { print("HELLO", $0) }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
if var value = try? subject.value() {
    value.append(1)
    subject.on(.next(value))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with the answer @EtienneJézéquel gave...

The `public static func ObservableType.from(_:)` function returns an Observable whereas the `BehaviorSubject.init(value:)` creates a BehaviorSubject which must then be converted to an Observable before you can `map(_:)` it.

Also, it might help to understand better when you realize you don't append to the array that is contained by the BehaviorSubject, instead you emit a *new* array using it. That's why Etienne's code first copies the current array out of the subject using `value() throws` and appends to the copy and then pushes the new array into the subject using `onNext(_:)`.

Lastly, don't make subjects `var`s they should always be `let`s because you don't want to reseat them after setting up chains to them.